# Using storage.objectAccessControls.insert for google cloud storage

Tags: cloud, storage, google-cloud-storage

test URL :https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1beta2/storage.objectAccessControls.insert

I have  send  the  request  like  this:

---

```
Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer <AUTH TOKEN HERE>
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{

 "entity": "user-email",
 "role": "READER",
 "email": "WAITER@GMAIL.COM",
 "kind": "storage#objectAccessControl"
}
```

============================================

```
Response


400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

=====================================
who  can  tell me   where  I  make  mistakes?  Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "entity" field should be "user-" and then the user's email address.

In your case, the correct fields would be:

```
{
  "entity": "user-waiter@gmail.com",
  "role": "READER"
}
```

These are all the fields you need.

Comment: some email  seems  cannot  be  used  as  entity. Does that  has some requires  like the email  must had been auth by google?

Comment: The emails must be associated with a Google account.

Comment: Really  appreciate  for your help~